# SQL: How do you handle conditional delete?

Tags: sql

I'm puzzled on how to write a stored procedure to handle a conditional delete.

I have a table with 4 columns (`ID`, `A`, `B`, `C`) and the data in the table looks like this:

```
ID  | A             | B     | C
----------------------------------
1   | Debbie Jones  |       |   
2   | John Jones    |       |
3   | James Jones   |       |
```

Columns `A`, `B`, and `C` hold a person's name. How would I write a stored procedure that will delete `Debbie Jones` row and not affect the other two rows with `B` and `C` column being an empty string?

Answer (score 4):

```
delete from YourLousyTableName
where A='Debbie'AND B='Jones'
```

assuming that ID=1 A='Debbie' B='Jones' C=''

Answer (score 2):

You need another condition then.  If you want to delete Debbie Jones, then you need to indicate that in your condition, either by specifying that column A = "Debbie Jones" or that the ID column is equal to 1.

This assumes, of course, that the values in the ID and A columns are unique and can uniquely identify the row.

Answer (score 1):

I may not be understanding your question completely but are you looking for something like this?

```
delete from Table
where [Name] = 'Debbie Jones';
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `DELETE FROM table WHERE A = "Debbie Jones";`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your example needs to be formatted correctly in your question (use the code tag!)

Second of all, I assume you're trying to avoid the mistake of deleting by name because there can be duplicate names. In that case, you probably want to delete only by the ID number.

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID=4

|ID|       A      |  B  |  C  |
|==|==============|=====|=====|
| 1| Debbie Jones | " " | " " |
| 2| John Jones   | " " | " " |
| 3| James Jones  | " " | " " |
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will need something like stored procedure for this type of situation. any how try this,

```
create procedure prcDelUsingID
@UID <Data Type of the ID column> 
as
delete from <Your Table Name>
where ID=@UID
```

execute stored procedure as follows,

```
prcDelUsingID <ID of the Debbie Jones>
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out that a parameter is probably necessary rather than hard-coding who should be deleted. -1 for implying that simple SQL statements don't necessarily need to be in stored procedures

Comment: Hey Tom, 
guess account balance is zero with that. :) :) 
I also agree with your view. But I think that is what Jack is searching for... In other hand I think when it comes to DB related application development it's good to use stored procedures. It prevent SQL Injection attacks. what you say ....

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following command:

```
x=sqldf(select * from [table_name] where A!='Derbie Jones')
```